# Javascript/React: Why is minute and seconds in timer not shown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, jsx

I wrote code for the following two websites:
https://konekto.world/ (FormEmergencyType)
https://konekto.world/emergency_details (AffectedState).
However, I want both files to look similar and like the which they do not yet.
Below you can see both function definitions:
File ”AffectedState.js”

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Grid, Box, IconButton, Link, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import ArrowForward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CONST from '../utils/Constants';
import RadioButtonGroup from '../SOS/RadioButtonGroup';
import RadioButton from '../SOS/RadioButton';

const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    // background: 'white',
    border: 'black',
    'border-width': 'medium',
    'margin-top': '80px',
    background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    'border-radius': '20px'
  },
  item: {
    // background: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    //background: 'white',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'margin-top': '10px'
  },
  label: {
    // background: 'white'
  }
  // forwardbutton: {
  //   'text-align': 'right'
  // }
}));

export default function AffectedState(props) {
  const classes = styles; //React HOOK API => looks nice
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      className={classes.container}
      direction="column"
      spacing={2}
    >
      <Grid item sm={12} className={classes.item}>
        <Typography variant="h5">What happened?</Typography>
        {/* <Box className={classes.label}>A</Box> */}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={12} className={classes.item}>
        <RadioButtonGroup>
          <RadioButton name="AffectedState" value="1" label="Cannot move" />
          <RadioButton
            name="AffectedState"
            value="2"
            label="Intensive bleeding"
          />
          <RadioButton name="AffectedState" value="3" label="Life at stake" />
          <RadioButton name="AffectedState" value="4" label="Frostbite" />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
        <Grid />
        <Grid item sm={12} className={(classes.item, classes.forwardbutton)}>
          <Link component={RouterLink} to="/summary_page" no-underline>
            <IconButton
              //onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}
              edge="start"
              // className={classes.forwardbutton}
              color="black"
              //TODO can we change color and move it to right?
            >
              <ArrowForward />
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

File ”FormEmergencyType.js”

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Grid,
  Box,
  IconButton,
  Link,
  Typography,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel
} from '@material-ui/core';
import ArrowForward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CONST from '../utils/Constants';
import CheckBoxGroup from './CheckBoxGroup';
import CheckBox from './CheckBox';
import SOSButton from './SOSButton';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    // background: 'white',
    border: 'black',
    'border-width': 'medium',
    'margin-top': '80px',
    background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    'border-radius': '20px'
  },
  item: {
    // background: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    //background: 'white',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'margin-top': '10px'
  },
  label: {
    // background: 'white'
  }
  // forwardbutton: {
  //   'text-align': 'right'
  // }
});

class FormEmergencyType extends React.Component {
  //const classes = useStyles(); //React HOOK API => looks nice
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //const { classes } = props;
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {
      ambulance: props.emergencyTypes.ambulance,
      fire_service: props.emergencyTypes.fire_service,
      car_service: props.emergencyTypes.car_service,
      police: props.emergencyTypes.police,
      emergency_contacts: props.emergencyTypes.emergency_contacts
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    //console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleChange(event, checked) {
    //let new_state = { emergencytype: this.state };
    let new_state = this.state;

    // console.log(event.target.value);
    // console.log(checked);

    switch (event.target.value) {
      case 'ambulance':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['ambulance'] = checked;
        new_state['ambulance'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'fire_service':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['fire_service'] = checked;
        new_state['fire_service'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'police':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['police'] = checked;
        new_state['police'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'car_service':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['car_service'] = checked;
        new_state['car_service'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'emergency_contacts':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['car_service'] = checked;
        new_state['emergency_contacts'] = checked;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    //this.setState(new_state.emergencytype);
    this.setState(new_state);
    // console.log(this.state);
    this.props.handleEmergencyType(new_state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        className={this.classes.container}
        direction="column"
        spacing={2}
      >
        <Grid item sm={12} className={this.classes.item}>
          <CheckBoxGroup>
            <CheckBox
              title="Ambulance"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['ambulance']}
              value="ambulance"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Fire Service"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['fire_service']}
              value="fire_service"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Police"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['police']}
              value="police"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Car Service"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['car_service']}
              value="car_service"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Emergency Contacts"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['emergency_contacts']}
              value="emergency_contacts"
            />
          </CheckBoxGroup>
          <Grid />
          <Grid
            item
            sm={12}
            className={(this.classes.item, this.classes.forwardbutton)}
          >
            <SOSButton onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(FormEmergencyType);
```

I have already tried changing the affected state component to a class but this also does not work. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question in the title, but for the aspect part, I believe that you are not sending the style props correctly. I checked in the inspector and the second component doesn't have access to the styles you wrote in your css-in-js.

Try checking if you are sending/receiving the props correctly or try accessing them directly by:

`className={this.props.classes.container}`